# Do we often use command forms for verbs that used for accidental situations, for example, "don't spill water", "don't bump into objects"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

When we command somebody to do something, we told him not to do things on purpose.

Verbs such as "**spill**" or "**bump**" are often used in accidental situations.

Can we use these verbs in command forms, for example, "**don't spill water**", "**don't bump into objects**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use these verbs in command forms!

Here's some example sentences:

"Don't spill water, these electronics aren't waterproof."

"Don't spill water on the carpet again."

"Don't bump into my art project, it's fragile."

"Don't bump into people without apologizing afterwards."

Comment: Also helpful would be to mention that the ‘command form’ is called the imperative mood.

Comment: We can also say "Be careful not to spill any water."